# "Hidden Wallet" onion site

Tags: fraud

I was assigned a wallet by "Hidden Wallet" onion site - my BTC never arrived cause its a scam. I have the wallet address and proof that it was assigned to me under username and password - Can I get my bitcoins back or send from that wallet to another ?

Comment: Welcome to Bitcoin.SE! Please see this [question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9046/why-is-my-transaction-not-getting-confirmed-and-what-can-i-do-about-it), some of the answers there may be of assistance for your situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the private keys for the address, then you could import said keys into compatible wallet software and send the btc back to an address you fully control.

If you don't have the private keys and can't access your coins on the onion site, then you will have to contact the site admin to get your coins back.

Comment: Thank you chytrik but the contact address for admin is also false. any way to obtain the keys somehow if I give you the address??

Comment: If you have just the bitcoin address, then no, you cannot get the private key from it. Sorry for your loss :( If you could somehow get a private key from an address, then the bitcoin network would be broken. Bitcoin addresses are public, you can search through the blockchain history on any block explorer website and see all of the addresses ever used. So it is safe to share a bitcoin address with others. WARNING: Do not give your **private key** to anyone, ever! If you do, they'll be able to steal your bitcoins easily.

Comment: about the key....I have two legit wallets but I dont have the keys - where do I find them?

Comment: That depends on the software, there should be either a 'mnemonic seed phrase' you can write down, or some sort of 'show/dump priv keys' command. Wallet software manages private keys in the background, if you've used the wallet a bit it will likely dump a whole bunch of private keys on request. A single mnemonic seed phrase can be used to derive many addresses, but not all wallets use the same key generation scheme. Some may simply offer the ability to back up each individual private/public keypairs instead.

Comment: Thanks for the info - pardon my ignorance - these wallets are with the exchanges that I buy BTC from - I'll see if can find anything - can you perhaps suggest a wallet "away" from the exchanges?

Comment: if you want to communicate further via email - slangspoor@protonmail.com

Comment: @Slangspoor if you are using an exchange as a wallet then you will not have access to the private keys, the exchange operator will control those (and send withdrawal txs at your request). Selecting an actual wallet to use (one where you control the keys) will depend on what level of security/usability you desire, there are many options available. For large amounts, use a hardware wallet like a trezor or ledger. For smaller amounts, a mobile wallet may suit your needs. There are lots of good resources online concerning wallet selection. Shop around, be prudent.

Comment: Go to https://bitcoin.org/en/choose-your-wallet and click on the various wallets. Check out what it says for "control over your money" for each. With some wallets you control your money. With other "wallets" they are really third party custodian services, of which many are scammers just waiting to run away with your money.

Answer (score 1):

Based on a Bitcoin address you cannot get your money back. You also need a private key for that.

As the developer of the real [HiddenWallet](https://github.com/nopara73/HiddenWallet), which is a desktop application, not an online website I encountered this scam many times. Your money is lost, sorry about that.

One more thing to consider is, if you were using the same password at other places, then you probably want to change it.